# How do I continue a large project next day without R lagging/stalling reloading code from previous work?

Tags: r, rstudio, data-analysis

I'm doing a project for class that involves 12 csv files which I joined into one mega csv, but the problem is that it's quite a large dataset that has 6million rows.

Everyday I boot up Rstudio to reload the project and repopulate the environment pane data by running my code, it just takes forever. I was waiting 10 minutes just now for the command "view(df)"

The weird thing is, Once that initial hurdle of long compute times or lag or whatever is going on is completed, I don't really get any more long load times or lag.

Sorry I can't articulate this more clearly being new to R programming for last few months

please let me know if more information is needed

I'm not sure what to try to fix this

Comment: Loading a 6M row data set should not take long. If that is one of the bottlenecks, what code are you using? (it will be easier to help if you can profile your code and include any that is slow: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Profiling.html).   I have found that the `view()` command can be quite slow for even medium-sized data. You might consider commenting out that line, or using `view(head(data))` or similar if there is a subset of the data you need to look at regularly.

Comment: You can save object(s) with long compute times and reload them in new sessions. Enter `?save()` in the console for the documentation.